# Intersection product of pulled back divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I hope this question doesn't sound lame, but I have a few problems in understanding the notion of Intersection product.

Clearly, for a (Weil) divisor $D$ we have the first Chern class $c_1(\mathcal{O}(D)) \in H^2(X,\mathbb{R})$, where $\mathcal{O}(D)$ is the corresponding line bundle. Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a morphism of projective varieties. Let $C$ be a curve in $X$ and $D$ be a divisor on $Y$. I want to compute the intersection product $f^*(\mathcal{O}(D)).C$.

By definition, this is 
$$ f^*(\mathcal{O}(D)).C = c_1(f^*\mathcal{O}(D)).C = \int_C c_1(f^*\mathcal{O}(D)) = \int_C f^*(c_1(\mathcal{O}(D)) $$.

So far, so good. I am wondering now, whether we are able to identify the right-hand side with
$$ \int_{f(C)} c_1(\mathcal{O}(D)) = \mathcal{O}(D).f(C)?$$
Why would this be a correct thought? Or why not?

Comment: This is more or less correct, except that in general you will need $f_*(C)$ (pushforward as a cycle class, or homology class), rather than just the set-theoretic image of $C$. Look for "projection formula", for instance in Fulton's book.

Comment: Another small correction is that in general if $D$ is only a Weil divisor, these intersection products are not well defined (for example, there is no "corresponding line bundle", and no Chern class in cohomology). Rather, you need $D$ to be Cartier. If $X$ is smooth, there is no problem.

Comment: Dear Nefertiti, thanks for your fast response. Gladly, $X$ is smooth and projective, hence we're not in trouble.  How does the pushforward of a cycle class, $f_*(C)$ relate to the image $f(C)$?

Comment: Let me be a bit more precise and use square brackets $[]$ to denote the class (in the Chow group, or homology group) of a closed subset. Then if $C \rightarrow f(C)$ is finite of degree $d$, we define $f_*([C]) = d \cdot [f(C)]$. If not, define $f_*([C])=0$.

Comment: So, when I want to compute $f^*(\mathcal{O}(D)).[C]$ and I think of cycle classes, we have $c_1(f^*(\mathcal{O}(D)) \in H^2(X,\mathbb{R})$ and $[C] \in H^{2n-2}(X,\mathbb{R})$, where $n$ is the $\dim X$.
Hence, $g_*(f^*(\mathcal{O}(D)).[C]) = \mathcal{O}(D).[f_*(C)] = d \cdot \mathcal{O}(D).[f(C)]$ by projection formula as you said, where $d$ is the degree of $C \to f(C)$ and $g$ the given map in the projection formula. Is that the correct way to write it down? How do can I get rid of the map $g$, since I only want to compute $f^*(\mathcal{O}(D)).[C]$?

Comment: Or asked in another way being more precise: I know that $\mathcal{O}(D)$ is nef or ample on $Y$ and $C$ gets either contracted to a point or not. Then $g_*(f^*(\mathcal{O}(D)).[C]) = \mathcal{O}(D).[f_*(C)] = d \cdot \mathcal{O}(D).[f(C)]$. This is positive or equal to zero, depending on the property of $\mathcal{O}(D)$ or whether $dim f(C) = 0$ or not.

Comment: I don't understand where you got the map $g$ from. You should apply the projection formula to the map $f$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I looked up the wrong projection formula. The right one should be $f_*(c_1(f^*(\mathcal{O}(D)).[C]) = c_1(\mathcal{O}(D)).[f_*(C)]$, right?

Comment: That's right. I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: One last thing needs to be clarified: How do I obtain a result for $c_1(f^*(\mathcal{O}(D)).[C]$ by knowing the result of $f_*(c_1(f^*(\mathcal{O}(D)).[C])$? Say, $\mathcal{O}(D)$ is ample and $f(C)$ is a curve in $C$. Then $ f_*(c_1(f^*(\mathcal{O}(D)).[C]) = d\cdot (c_1(\mathcal{O}(D)).[f(C)] > 0$. What does that say about $(c_1(f^*(\mathcal{O}(D)).[C]$ itself? And how do I know whether $f(C)$ is a curve anyway$

Comment: In the end the projection formula is telling you that $f_*$ applied to a certain zero-cycle on $Y$ gives you a certain zero-cycle on $X$. But $f_*$ preserves the degree of zero-cycles, so the two sides have the same degree. As for $f(C)$: I can't answer that for you, because it depends on $f$ and $C$. I am just trying to confirm that your original question has (essentially) a positive answer.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for your help!